# I would like to convert a pivot table's column data to rows (unpivot a table)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe that I created from an Excel file of the following form:

```
            Ticker 0  Ticker 1  Ticker 2  Delta 0  ...  Gamma 1  Gamma 2  IL  Var
2019-01-01      -0.0      -1.0      -1.0      0.0  ...     -3.0      2.0  10    5
2019-01-02       0.0      -0.0      -1.0     -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0  10    5
2019-01-03       2.0      -1.0       1.0      0.0  ...     -0.0     -2.0  10    5
2019-01-04       1.0       0.0       0.0     -1.0  ...     -0.0     -1.0  10    5
2019-01-05       1.0      -1.0      -0.0     -1.0  ...     -0.0     -1.0  10    5
2019-01-06       2.0       1.0       1.0     -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0  10    5
```

Given that on each date, the data on *Ticker i* corresponds to the data on *Delta i* and *Gamma i* and so I wish to make a table of the following form:

```
Date        Ticker Delta Gamma  IL  Var
2019-01-01  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
2019-01-01  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
2019-01-01  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
2019-01-01  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
2019-01-01  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
2019-01-01  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
2019-01-02  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
2019-01-02  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
.
.
.
2019-01-03  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
.
.
.
.
2019-01-04  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5  
2019-01-05  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5 
2019-01-06  NaN    NaN   NaN   10   5
```

I tried to use the `pd.melt()` method but I don't know how to make the date appear multiple times...

To recreate a similar dataframe I used the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

l=[]

for i in range(3):
    l.append('Ticker ' + str(i))

for i in range(3):
    l.append('Delta ' + str(i))

for i in range(3):
    l.append('Gamma ' + str(i))

dates = pd.date_range('20190101', periods=6)

data = np.random.randn(6, len(l))

df = pd.DataFrame(data.round(0), index = dates, columns = l)

df['IL']=10

df['Var']=5

df
Out[9]: 
            Ticker 0  Ticker 1  Ticker 2  Delta 0  ...  Gamma 1  Gamma 2  IL  Var
2019-01-01      -0.0      -1.0      -1.0      0.0  ...     -3.0      2.0  10    5
2019-01-02       0.0      -0.0      -1.0     -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0  10    5
2019-01-03       2.0      -1.0       1.0      0.0  ...     -0.0     -2.0  10    5
2019-01-04       1.0       0.0       0.0     -1.0  ...     -0.0     -1.0  10    5
2019-01-05       1.0      -1.0      -0.0     -1.0  ...     -0.0     -1.0  10    5
2019-01-06       2.0       1.0       1.0     -1.0  ...      0.0      0.0  10    5

[6 rows x 11 columns]
```

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: where do 0,1,2, labels go in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're converting from a wide format to a longitudinal format. Try

```
df.reset_index(inplace = True)

df = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Ticker', 'Delta', 'Gamma'], i = 'index', j = 'timepoint', sep = " ")
```

where the stubnames of your variables are `['Ticker', 'Delta', 'Gamma']`, you're identifying rows based on their dates, and the timepoints are 0, 1, 2.

```
Out[19]: 
                      Var  IL  Ticker  Delta  Gamma
index      timepoint                               
2019-01-01 0            5  10    -2.0   -1.0   -0.0
2019-01-02 0            5  10     0.0   -0.0    1.0
2019-01-03 0            5  10    -1.0   -0.0   -2.0
2019-01-04 0            5  10     1.0   -0.0   -1.0
2019-01-05 0            5  10    -1.0   -1.0   -1.0
2019-01-06 0            5  10     2.0   -1.0   -1.0
2019-01-01 1            5  10     0.0    1.0   -1.0
2019-01-02 1            5  10     1.0   -1.0    2.0
2019-01-03 1            5  10    -1.0   -0.0   -0.0
2019-01-04 1            5  10     0.0    1.0    0.0
2019-01-05 1            5  10     0.0    1.0    2.0
2019-01-06 1            5  10     1.0    1.0   -0.0
2019-01-01 2            5  10    -0.0   -2.0    0.0
2019-01-02 2            5  10    -1.0   -2.0   -0.0
2019-01-03 2            5  10    -1.0    1.0   -1.0
2019-01-04 2            5  10     0.0    2.0   -1.0
2019-01-05 2            5  10    -0.0    2.0    1.0
2019-01-06 2            5  10    -2.0    1.0    1.0
```

Add

```
df.sort_values(by=['index', 'timepoint']).reset_index()
```

To sort by the date and timepoint, then use `reset_index()` to return them to columns.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `Ticker 0  Ticker 1  Ticker 2  Delta 0  ...  Gamma 1  Gamma 2` are essentially `multi-index` disguised as strings.  `Ticker 0` carries two labels `Ticker` and `0` that need to be split. See code below,

```
df2 = df.set_index(['IL','Var'],append=True)  # IL and Var are not multiindex and need to be separated.

df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split(' ',expand=True)  # Spilt Ticker/Gamma/Delta and 0/1/2

df2.stack().reset_index(['IL','Var'])   # Melting
```